# Accessing the Airflow default variables outside of operator

Tags: python, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I am trying to create a dynamic tasklist to check the previous batch runs for the day got completed or not. In order to achieve that, I have the Timings(HHMM) stored in the Airflow variable and I have used the datetime.now() variable to get the current HHMM and creates a list of previous runs. But as the Airflow dag gets validated everytime, it picks up the latest date and time and it generates new previous task list based on that.

I was trying to see instead of comparing the datetime.now(), using the {{ ds }} and {{ ts }} default airflow variables to avoid the above issue. But it treats these variables as String or not able recognize those as variables and throwing ts/ds variable not defined.

is there way/workaround to access these variables outside of the operators as the above logic is to create a list of dynamic tasks to be run based on to check the previous batch run completion.

Thanks in Advance.

```
from datetime import datetime,timedelta,date
from pytz import timezone, utc
import pendulum

## Below would come from Airflow variable.
dag_times = ["0700", "0715", "0730" ,"0730", "0930","1130","1330","1630","2000"]

## This is the code to get the current time.. this is keep changing as the airflow validates the DAG.
current_dag_time = datetime.now().astimezone(timezone('US/Pacific')).strftime('%H%M')

schedule_run_time = min(dag_times, key=lambda x:abs(int(x)-int(current_dag_time)))
current_run = dag_times.index(schedule_run_time)
print("current_run",current_run)
intra_day_time = dag_times[dag_times.index(schedule_run_time)-1] if current_run > 0 else schedule_run_time
previous_runs = []
if current_run > 0:
    # print(dag_times.index(schedule_run_time))
    previous_runs = dag_times[0:dag_times.index(schedule_run_time)] 
else:
    previous_runs.append(dag_times[-1])

previous_run_tasks=[]

for dag_name in previous_runs:
    item = {}
    if int(dag_name) == 0:
        if date.today().weekday() == 0 :
            start_time =-52
            end_time = 4
        else:
            start_time =-24
            end_time = 24
        # poke_task_name = "SAMPLE_BOX_%s" % dag_name
        item = {"poke_task_name": "SAMPLE_BOX_%s" % dag_name, "start_time":start_time, "end_time":end_time}
    elif int(dag_name) > 0 :
        start_time =0
        end_time = 24
        poke_task_name = "SAMPLE_BOX_%s" % dag_name
        item = {"poke_task_name": "SAMPLE_BOX_%s" % dag_name, "start_time":start_time, "end_time":end_time}
    else:
        print("error")
    previous_run_tasks.append(item)
    print(previous_run_tasks)

if int(schedule_run_time) == 0:
    if date.today().weekday() == 0 :
        start_time =-52
        end_time = 4
    else:
        start_time =-24
        end_time = 24
    poke_task_name = "SAMPLE_BOX_%s" % dag_times[-1]
    generate_task_name = "SAMPLE_BOX_%s" % schedule_run_time
elif int(schedule_run_time) > 0 :
    start_time =0
    end_time = 24
    poke_task_name = "SAMPLE_BOX_%s" % intra_day_time
    generate_task_name = "SAMPLE_BOX_%s" % schedule_run_time
else:
    print("error")

print("start_time::::",start_time)
print("end_time::::",end_time)
print("generate_task_name::::",generate_task_name)
print("poke_task_name::::",poke_task_name)
```

Comment: Provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please, provide an example with {{ ds }} and {{ ts }}, how are you trying to run them? That will enable me to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 2):

These Airflow default variables are only instantiated in the context of a task instance for a given DAG run, and thus they are only available in the templated fields of each operator. Trying to use them outside of this context will not work.

I have prepared a simple DAG with task that displays execution date (`ds`) as a parameter:

```
from airflow import macros
from airflow import models
from airflow.operators import bash_operator
import datetime

yesterday = datetime.datetime.combine(
    datetime.datetime.today() - datetime.timedelta(1),
    datetime.datetime.min.time())

default_args = {
            "start_date": yesterday,
            "retries": 1,
            "email_on_failure": False,
            "email_on_retry": False,
            "email": "youremail@host.com"
}

with models.DAG(
    'printing_the_execution_date_ts', 
    schedule_interval=datetime.timedelta(days=1), 
    default_args=default_args) as dag:

    printing_the_execution_date = bash_operator.BashOperator(
            task_id="display",
            bash_command="echo {{ ds }}"
    )

    printing_the_execution_date
```

The `{{ }}` brackets tell Airflow that this is a Jinja template.

You may also use `ts` variable which is the execution date in ISO 8601 format. Thus, in the dag run stamped with `2020-05-10`, this would render to:

```
'echo {{ ds }}'
echo 2020-05-10

'echo {{ ts }}'
echo 2020-05-10T00:00:00+00:00
```

I recommend you to take a look for this [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36730714/execution-date-in-airflow-need-to-access-as-a-variable) thread, where you can find example with using PythonOperator.